# delete specific rows from a flat file

Tags: ssis-2012

How to delete specific rows from a flat file on the basis of first 4 characters of a row?  For example; delete the rows starting with '1000'.  (After deleting these rows, the file will remain there with other rows that start with '2000', '3000', and so on.

Or, how to write the rows starting with '1000', '2000', and '3000' into different flat files?  (Each row has varying number of columns and columns have different width).

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please show a example, even if it doesn't work! :-)

Comment: Placed a DFT, read the source file, configured the FlatFile Connection Manager as 'Ragged'.  Then directed the rows to thru 'Conditional Split'.  In the DM between 'Source File' and 'Conditional Split', the first row of '2000' is appended at the end of the last row of '1000'.  (Because, '1000' row has less number of columns than '2000').